# How to find out the Send Id and Batch Id of an Asynchronous TriggeredSend

Tags: marketing-cloud, asynchronous, send-email

> Disclaimer: I'm new so I may not have the terminology down. I'm including links to the documentation on the Exact Target site regarding the APIs we are using.

We are using [Asynchronous Triggered Sends](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/submitting_a_triggered_send_definition_using_the_asynchronous_api/) to send emails from our application and we are using [Tracking Extracts](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/data_extract/#What_Is_a_Sent_Event_Extract_File) to get all of the Sent events and Open events. How can we get the SendId at the time that we do the Triggered Send? The Response that we get back is a list of status for each email single send that was in the triggered send request, but the field NewID is 0 for all the entries. Is the NewID the same as the SendID ? There is also something called the NewObjectID which is also 0.

If we use the Retrieve operation to get the result later, the NewID is still 0, even after the email has been delivered.

We need to store the Send Id in our own db so that we can correlate the Exact Target Tracking Data with our own internal data.

How do we get the SendID?

Comment: The above question assumed that the SendId was a unique id generated per send request. In fact, it identifies the triggered send definition and not a particular send. The BatchId + SendId identifies a particular group of emails sent at the same time. I was looking for a way to track individual emails sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out what I need to do is to implement Custom Send Logging. 
To do this, I needed to enable the send logging data extensions and then add a custom column (UniqueID).

Next I had to modify the our server code that initiates the Triggered Send using the SOAP API to pass along the UniqueID. This info is found below:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_tracking_results_for_one_to_one_triggered_sends/

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/#section_15